# Response from Ajax.BeginForm not coming with new model values

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc app and I am having some trouble after posting the form. In the Action I am creating a new model that I return in the end of the action. The problem is that the model passed has the same values than it has before the post (I checked it in the chrome developer tools)
Here is the code:

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MyViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult GetScore(MyViewModel userInputDetails)
        {
            userInputDetails.Name = "Meeee";
            userInputDetails.Gender = "Yes Please!";
            return PartialView("_MyPartialView", userInputDetails);
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetScore", "Test", new AjaxOptions()
                {
                    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    UpdateTargetId = "partialResult"
                }))
            {        
                <div id="partialResult">
                    @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", Model)
                </div>    
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_MyPartialView.cshtml

```
@model MvcAjaxUpdateTest.ViewModels.MyViewModel

<table class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Gender)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="submit" name="Go" /></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

"MyViewModel.cs"

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `ModelState.Clear()` in your controller method after changing values that have been posted back. Otherwise the view will continue to display the values from the posted back ModelState, even if the values in the Model are different.

Bear in mind this will also clear any ModelErrors, so make sure you wrap it all in a `if(ModelState.IsValid){ }`

ie:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MyViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetScore(MyViewModel userInputDetails)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                userInputDetails.Name = "Meeee";
                userInputDetails.Gender = "Yes Please!";
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            return PartialView("_MyPartialView", userInputDetails);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you could probably get away with just removing these values from the ModelState.

ie:

```
userInputDetails.Name = "Meeee";
userInputDetails.Gender = "Yes Please!";
ModelState.Remove("Name");
ModelState.Remove("Gender");
```